# How to change the default file/db location in Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating an application using asp.net mvc 5. I want to use Sqlite in the application.
I have installed Sqlite using Nuget.
The default file path of the database file is C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express. I want to create the file in the App_Data folder inside the application itself.

Currently I am using the following code to create and open the DB file: `SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test_database2.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");`

How can I change the default database file location in Sqlite?

Answer (score 1):

We can create the DB file in App_Data folder using the below code

```
SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|test_database2.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
```

Does anyone know how we can create the same file at some other location inside the application?